# Is there a way to configure rails console to re-run my initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have code in my application.rb file, that calls class methods that load certain objects into memory.  If I am in rails console and have to use "reload!" those objects are no longer in memory, and i have to quit and restart rails c.

This is the code for those initializers:

```
config.to_prepare do
    Const.load!
    Card.load!
    Position.load!
end
```

Note that this is different than just reloading an object that changes in lib, which I have seen answers on how to do.

Answer (score 0):

in your `application.rb` try this:

```
ActionDispatch::Callbacks.after
  Const.load!
  Card.load!
  Position.load!
end
```